# Will my device get locked again after update?

Tags: updates, sim-unlocking, samsung-captivate-glide

I've bought samsung captivate glide I-927 from eBay. It is locked with at&t by default, so seller unlocked device for me and it is working fine. It comes with Gingerbread 2.3.5 and I found that ICS update for this device available from Samsung kies (pc suite). Now the question is Will my device get locked again after update from GB to ICS???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, software updates do not mess around with carrier info like that. Your phone should still be set to work with AT&T after the latest update is applied. If updating the device meant reactivating the phone, many people would be unhappy because of activation fees.

Comment: I'm in India and seller have unlocked this for global GSM carriers. So is it still work with Indian GSM carrier after update? I'm asking you because you mention at&t in your answer.

Comment: I'm actually unsure if it will revert back in your case. I believe that will depend on what image you use to update your device.